# Command Prompt: access denied when run PowerShell

Tags: powershell, command-prompt

I got a problem when try to run powershell from command line. I typed powershell.exe when pop up window shows up in blue background saying: "This app cant run on your PC, to find version for your PC check publisher". Then command prompt gives message: "Access is denied."

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Comment: @Luke " unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming". Yes, thats the case I am having.

Comment: What is the code you are having issues with?

Comment: Anything, say echo "hello" will not work because of power shell issue. BUT it runs on WINDOWS PowerShell ISE.

Comment: Try to re-install .net framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My problem was that `C:/windows/system32/powershell.exe` was invalid as you can see on the image below:

[image]

I could found the right executable in `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\`.

So if this is your problem, try the following:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe .\my-script.ps1
```

Instead of this:

```
powershell.exe .\my-script.ps1
```